# Hide user reputation when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

When reviewing *First Posts* this isn't as much of an issue as most users posting for the first time have very little reputation, but for *Triage*, *Late Answers*, and *Documentation: Proposed Changes* I don't see how being able to see the reputation of the user who posted that question/answer is of any benefit to the reviewer. Personally, I think that seeing that information biases the reviewer toward more favorable reviews on questions/answers made by users with higher reputations.

At any rate, being able to see the reputation of users spoils some of the review audits (i.e. all of a sudden you see a question by a user with 20K reputation - hmmm...)

Shouldn't the review process simply be about the quality of the question/answer irrespective of who asked it or how active they are on SO?

Comment: *...being able to see the reputation of users spoils some of the review audits...* The audits are supposed to be easy. It's only to check and make sure you're paying attention and if you're stopping to look at the question more closely then it's done it's job.

Comment: @BSMP - sure maybe it isn't a big issue in terms of spoiling the review audits, but all the same, I do think seeing the user's reputation introduces an unwanted bias to the whole review process.

Comment: There is a tool for doing this if you want to hide them: http://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-gravatar-badges-and-reputation That said, you do eventually get used to the fact that users with more rep than you will post blatant tool requests.

Comment: Ok, but I'm suggesting that this be a feature implemented for all reviewers - not just ones who go to the trouble to hide the reputation from themselves using that tool.

Comment: I get that, just figured I'd point it out.